# Highlight search phrase within quickfix window listing

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, highlighting

One can change the search color of search terms with the `Search` highlight scheme.
Similarly one can change the color of a line in the quickfix window with `QuickFixLine`.

However, how does one change the colour of the search phrase within listing in the quick fix window?

A picture is worth 1000 word, hence in the following image, I `:vimgrep` searched for 'buffer', and I underlined some matches in yellow with a screen grab tool, is it possible to highlight them in vim (in particular Neovim)?:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Two ideas:

1. If you just want to highlight them, search with `/buffer` and make sure `hlsearch` is on. Or, for a more permanent solution, navigate to the quickfix window and use `:match Search /buffer/`
2. If you care more about filtering, I would do `:packadd cfilter`, which provides the `:Cfilter` command. Then a `:Cfilter /buffer/` gives you only entries with `buffer`, and `:colder` restores the original. (Of course, given that the original search was `buffer`, OP won't be able to limit in this way.)

Comment: Searching within the quick fix window does make it highlight. But then one has to type the search term twice. I wonder if there is anyway to make it automatically search for it upon opening the quickfix window.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `AutoCommand`.

See `:help QuickFixCmdPost` and `:help QuickFixCmdPost-example`.

```
                            *QuickFixCmdPost*
QuickFixCmdPost         Like QuickFixCmdPre, but after a quickfix
                        command is run, before jumping to the first
                        location. For |:cfile| and |:lfile| commands
                        it is run after the error file is read and
                        before moving to the first error.
                        See |QuickFixCmdPost-example|.
```

Also, from `:help CTRL-W_<Enter>`:

> When the quickfix window has been filled, two autocommand events are
> triggered.  First the 'filetype' option is set to "qf", which triggers the FileType event (also see |qf.vim|).  Then the BufReadPost event is triggered, using "quickfix" for the buffer name.  This can be used to perform some action on the listed errors.  Example:

```
au BufReadPost quickfix  setlocal modifiable
    \ | silent exe 'g/^/s//\=line(".") .. " "/'
    \ | setlocal nomodifiable
```

> This prepends the line number to each line.  Note the use of "=" in the substitute string of the ":s" command, which is used to evaluate an expression. The BufWinEnter event is also triggered, again using "quickfix" for the buffer name.

In your function, use `getmatches()` to extract the last one and execute `:match` on that string. Once you get it working, edit my answer to provide a workable script and delete this sentence. :)